# Invalid Label error when consuming USA Today Census API

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I'm trying to consume the USA Today Census API json service using jquery and jsonp. Here is the code:

```
var url = "http://api.usatoday.com/open/census/locations?api_key=yourapikeyhere&keyname=FIPS&sumlevid=3&keypat=36069&format=jsonp&callback=?";

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (result) {
                console.debug(result);
            }
        });
```

Here is the response if I hit the url in the browser, which is valid json:

```
{"request":{
        "keyname":"FIPS",
        "keypat":"36069",
        "sumlevid":"3",
        "year":"2010"},
    "response":[



    {"Placename":"Ontario","PlacenameFull":"Ontario County, N.Y.","FIPS":"36069","GNIS":"974133","StateAP":"N.Y.","StatePostal":"NY",
              "PctChange":"0.0768977",
              "Pop":"107931","PctHisp":"0.03408700","PctNonHisp":"0.96591300","PctWhite":"0.93650600","PctNonHispWhite":"0.91835500","PctBlack":"0.02253300","PctAmInd":"0.00255700","PctAsian":"0.01043300","PctNatHawOth":"0.00022200","PctTwoOrMore":"0.01666800","PctOther":"0.01108100","USATDiversityIndex":"0.16165100","PopSqMi":"167.60000000","LandSqMi":"644.10000000","WaterSqMi":"18.50000000","TotSqMi":"662.50000000","Lat":"42.8566949000","Long":"-77.3032768000","HousingUnits":"48193","PctVacant":"0.10736000"},



   "End"
   ]}
```

Firebug gives an "invalid label" error and doesn't return the result. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated the server, to support JSONP.  (I would have done it earlier, but I just got back from vacation.)

Answer (score 0):

It seem that the API you are using doesn't supports JSONP (the response is not wrapped in a function call). And when the script is executed it results in a syntax error because hash literals (`{...}`) are not allowed as top-level statements.

Make sure that the API supports JSONP, and if it does, make sure that you are using the correct name for the `callback` parameter.

If it doesn't supports JSONP you'll have to call it through a server-side language (or proxy requests to it).

---

JSONP works by wrapping a javascript literal in a function call, for example:

```
jsonp_callback({the: "response"});
```

If you implement fhe function `jsonp_callback()` and execute this script, your function will receive the response.

The server must explicitly support JSONP for this to work.